# Conditional Forwarding in HAProxy

Tags: haproxy

I just started using `HAProxy` and I have the following situation:

1. I have two backend services, lets call them `service A` and `service P`
2. I am trying to use a load balancer like `haproxy`
3. When a request comes in, assume that it has a `token` that is part of a HTTP header like `X-SOME-TOKEN` that is `httponly`
4. I want to extract this `token`, send to it `service A`, retrieve an `ID token`, attach it to a request for `service B` which, if returns HTTP status code 200, only then a success HTTP status code 200 and the JSON payload sent from `service B` is sent to client and if otherwise, HTTP status code 500 is sent to client.

My confusion is with part `3 and 4`. I am not sure if this can be done at the load balancing layer using `haproxy`. I have looked at the docs and read briefly about `acl`. If this can be done using `acl` what should be the possible approach?

To add more context, this is the configuration file I have with comments on where I would like to make changes:

```
global
  log /dev/log daemon
  maxconn 32768
  chroot /var/lib/haproxy
  user haproxy
  group haproxy
  daemon
  stats socket /var/lib/haproxy/stats user haproxy group haproxy mode 0640 level admin

  tune.bufsize 32768
  tune.ssl.default-dh-param 2048
  ssl-default-bind-ciphers ALL:!aNULL:!eNULL:!EXPORT:!DES:!3DES:!MD5:!PSK:!RC4:!ADH:!LOW@STRENGTH

defaults
   log     global
   mode    http
   option  log-health-checks
  option  log-separate-errors
  option  dontlog-normal
  option  dontlognull
  option  httplog
  option  socket-stats
  retries 3
  option  redispatch
  maxconn 10000
  timeout connect     5s
  timeout client     50s
  timeout server    450s

#listen stats
  #bind 0.0.0.0:80
  #bind :::80 v6only
  #stats enable
  #stats uri     /
  #stats refresh 5s
  #rspadd Server:\ haproxy/1.6

frontend testnode
  # I want to define all my urls here for which,
  # the load balancer needs to listen to on port 4200
  bind 127.0.0.1:4200
  mode http
  default_backend testnodebackend

backend testnodebackend
   # this is where I believe I need to add the proper functions
   # based on url endpoint like mydomain.com/endpoint, I want 
   # to decide where service A needs to be called for token exchange
   # this configuration currently points to two instances of the same 
   # server
   balance roundrobin
   option forwardfor
   http-request set-header X-Forwarded-Port %[dst_port]
   option httpchk HEAD / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost:localhost
   server node1 127.0.0.1:4201 check 
   server node2 127.0.0.1:4202 check
```

---

**EDIT**

I have found that custom request handlers can be added in `HAProxy` using Lua as a scripting language. I have already  set up my configuration which, can run "hello_world" examples from HAProxy. However, when it tries to load modules in Lua (like socket module), there is an import error. As soon as I have that fixed, I will add more on how setup these custom request handlers.